# Retrieve only one record from LEFT JOIN

Tags: sql, join, group-by, aggregate-functions

I have two tables that one stores advertisements (`ads`) and other stores images (`images`). `images` usually contain more than one images per each records in `ads`.

`ads` table

```
+------------+------------+
|ad_id       |title       |
+------------+------------+
|1           |sample1     |
+------------+------------+
|2           |sample2     |
+------------+------------+
```

`images` table

```
+------------+------------+
|image_id    |image       |
+------------+------------+
|1           |1.jpg       |
+------------+------------+
|1           |2.jpg       |
+------------+------------+
|2           |3.jpg       |
+------------+------------+
```

What I want to do is make a list of ads with one image per each record in `ads` and currently using following sql query.

```
SELECT a.`title`, i.`image`
FROM ads a
LEFT JOIN `images` i ON i.`id` = a.`id`
```

but this returns me three records instead of two ads, which contains duplicate records from `ads` as `images` contains two records of images.

How do I limit only one image per one record in the ads.

Any help would be really appreciated. TIA

PS:
current output is like

```
sample1, 1.jpg
sample1, 2.jpg
sample2, 3.jpg
```

But I'm expecting

```
sample1, 1.jpg
sample2, 3.jpg
```

or

```
sample1, 2.jpg
sample2, 3.jpg
```

Comment: What's your dbms? and your expect result?

Comment: Because there are two `image_id= 1` rows in     `images` table

Comment: Hi. This is a faq. Please always google many clear, concise & specific versions/phrasings of your question/problem/goal with & without your particular strings/names & read many answers. Add relevant keywords you discover to your searches. If you don't find an answer then post, using 1 variant search as title & keywords for tags. See the downvote arrow mouseover text. When you do have a non-duplicate code question to post please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LEFT JOIN` means will be on the table which on the left side by the `ON` condition but it will be all match by `id = 1` or `id = 2`

You can try to use aggregate function `MIN` or `MAX on`i.image` column to make your expectation.

If you want to get `1.jpg` you can use `MIN` otherwise use `MAX`

```
CREATE TABLE ads(
  ad_id INT,
  title VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO ads VALUES (1,'sample1');
INSERT INTO ads VALUES (2,'sample2');

CREATE TABLE images(
  image_id INT,
  image VARCHAR(50)
);


INSERT INTO images VALUES(1,'1.jpg');
INSERT INTO images VALUES(1,'2.jpg');
INSERT INTO images VALUES(2,'3.jpg');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
SELECT a.`title`,MIN(i.`image`)
FROM ads a
LEFT JOIN `images` i ON i.`image_id` = a.`ad_id` 
GROUP BY  a.`title`;

| title   | MIN(i.`image`) |
| ------- | -------------- |
| sample1 | 1.jpg          |
| sample2 | 3.jpg          |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/qdAnb2NJTW6BbRhAuiJ5dn/0)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way is probably a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT a.title,
       (SELECT i.image
        FROM image` i 
        WHERE i.id = a.id 
        LIMIT 1
       ) as image
FROM ads a;
```

This returns an *arbitrary* image.  You can add an `ORDER BY` to the subquery to get a particular image, such as:

- `ORDER BY rand()` to get a *random* image
- `ORDER BY i.id` to get the smallest `id`
- `ORDER BY i.createDate DESC` to get the newest one
- and so on

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT OG.tittle as Title, 
       OG.image as Image
FROM 
(
SELECT a.title as tittle, 
       i.image as image,
        row_number() over (Partition BY i.image_id ORDER BY i.image_id ASC  ) as rn
FROM ads a
LEFT JOIN images i ON i.id = a.id
) OG
WHERE rn =1
```

This query will only display  one image per one record based on row number based filtering .

For more info on joins click here https://medium.com/@cdaniel7/run-down-of-sql-joins-434d9d03f2d